# When i run my code the menus appear vertical not horizontal how do i change this?

Tags: java, jmenu

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIA54.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Task1 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Task1 a = new Task1();
    }

    public Task1() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400,500);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu help = new JMenu("help");

        menuBar.add(help);
        menuBar.add(file);
        frame.add(menuBar);

        JMenuItem load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem ("About");

        help.add(about);
        file.add(exit);
        file.add(save);
        file.add(load);


    }
}
```

This code for some reason when I run it the menus appear vertical not horizontal and I don't know why. I know this is a basic thing but I cant think of a solution that doesn't result in errors.

Comment: Which menus, the `File` and `help` menus?

Comment: Yeah those two menus are vertical.

Comment: (Deleted my other comment.) I think I see the issue.

Comment: I think you're adding the menu bar as regular content.  Instead of calling `add()`, use `frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);` to set the menu bar of the frame.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using `JFrame.add()` instead of `JFrame.setMenuBar()`. The former adds components (which `JMenuBar` is) to the inner `contentPane` of the `JFrame`. Change your code from this:

```
frame.add(menuBar);
```

To this:

```
frame.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Comment: Also, Swing is not thread safe.  The ctor of `Task1` should be called on the EDT.

Comment: Brian and markspace you were both right thanks guys, cant believe I missed something so easy, I appreciate the help thank you.